# Can't install express, no such file package.json

Tags: node.js, express

I have a problem. I cant install express with command: `npm install express`

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files\Express\nodekb\package.json'

> npm WARN nodekb No description npm WARN nodekb No repository field.
> npm WARN nodekb No README data npm WARN nodekb No license field.
> 
> npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\Express\nodekb\node_modules npm ERR!
> code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall mkdir npm ERR! Error:
> EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program
> Files\Express\nodekb\node_modules' npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM:
> operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program
> Files\Express\nodekb\node_modules'] npm ERR!   cause: npm ERR!    {
> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program
> Files\Express\nodekb\node_modules' npm ERR!      errno: -4048, npm
> ERR!      code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir', npm ERR!     
> path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Express\\nodekb\\node_modules' }, npm ERR!  
> stack: npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
> \'C:\\Program Files\\Express\\nodekb\\node_modules\'', npm ERR!  
> errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
> npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Express\\nodekb\\node_modules' }
> npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text
> editor or antivirus), npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access
> it. npm ERR! npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions
> issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and
> its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again
> as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\Matea\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-15T18_22_38_969Z-debug.log
```

Any help will be nice. And I¨m sorry if I put this in wrong way...

Comment: Looks like you are missing a package.json file.

Comment: Have you done `npm init` first?

Answer (score 0):

> The operation was rejected by your operating system.
>   It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text
>   editor or antivirus), or that you lack permissions to access
>   it. If you believe this might be a permissions
>   issue, please double-check the permissions of the file and
>   its containing directories, or try running the command again
>   as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

It's pretty clear the user you're running `npm` as doesn't have the correct permissions to create folders in the privileged paths mentioned in the first half of the error text.

`cd` to a Node project in a place within the local filesystem where you have permissions, or run `npm` in an Administrator-level command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are in the directory that you want your project to be in.  Then run `npm init`.  This will initialize the node project.  By doing this you will also create a package.json file and you can then `npm install` anything you want.  If you want to automatically save the npm packages to the package.json, run `npm install my_package --save`, substituting "my_package" for whatever package you want.  For example, express.